# Split a string in two on the middle comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split a string into 2 parts based on the middle comma.

- There can be an unlimited amount of commas
- Assume there will be an odd number of commas at all time

From:

```
"1, 4, a, fdsa, 53, dfs, sdfg, klk"
```

To:

```
"1, 4, a, fdsa" and "53, dfs, sdfg, klk"
```

Comment: What approach have you tried and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some basic arithmetic:

```
splitstring = mystring.split(',')
print(','.join(splitstring[:len(splitstring)//2]) + ' and ' + ','.join(splitstring[len(splitstring)//2:]))
```

In case you want to eliminate extra spaces from the original string after the middle comma you can just strip them, so add to each `join` statement:

```
','.join(...).strip()
```

Comment: This doesn't run btw

Comment: @MatthewHart Come-on, you could have fixed a slip of the parenthesis. Fixed. See how nice Eric was ;)?

Comment: sorry I was literally just finishing work. I'll give you a +1 to make up for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Regards. I will use your string as example :

`S = "1, 4, a, fdsa, 53, dfs, sdfg, klk"`

Assuming that the number of `,` will be odd. So, my *idea* is to ***locate*** the middle `,` (this would be the *(n+1)th* `,`). To do this, we can apply the string method `.find`.

`S.find(',')` will return `1`. (since the first `,` is at index `1`)

`S.find(',', 2)` will return `4`. (since after the 3rd character on your string, the first `,` is at index `4`)

Let the number of `,` in the string be *2n+1*. Since you don't know the location of the middle `,` (for other strings) you can use loop as many as *(n+1)* times to locate the index of the middle `,`. You may use `S.count(',')` to find the number of `,`'s (this will be *n*).

Let the location (or index) be `m`. So that after this, you can create two strings :
`A=S[0:m-1];` and `B=S[m+1:];`
to produce the desired split.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just splitting and rejoining the first half.

```
>>> s = '1, 4, a, fdsa, 53, dfs, sdfg, klk'

>>> *a, b = s.split(', ', s.count(',') // 2 + 1)
>>> ', '.join(a), b
('1, 4, a, fdsa', '53, dfs, sdfg, klk')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your sting be input_str, then

```
s = input_str.split(',')
string_length = len(s)
print(','.join(s[0:string_length//2]) +" and " + ','.join(s[string_length//2:]))
```

will print what you need.

Comment: Also, check out the help page - format code by indenting it by four spaces (highlight it and press Ctrl+K) instead of manually putting it in backticks.

Comment: Sorry folks, @StefanPochmann,  edited for Python 3 and , also renamed the variable , Tim Pietzcker, indented by four spaces :). Thank you.